# PHP Regex replace all instances of a character in similar strings

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a file that contains a collection strings. All of the strings begin with the same set of characters and end with the same character. I need to find all of the strings that match a certain pattern, and then remove particular characters from them before saving the file. Each string looks like this:

```
Data_*: " ... "
```

where `Data_` is the same for each string, the asterisk is an incrementing integer that is either two or three digits, and the colon and the double quotation marks are the same for each string. The `...` is completely different in every string and it's the part of each I need to work with. I need to remove all double quotation marks from the `...` , preserving the enclosing double quotation marks. I don't need to replace them, just remove them.

So for example, I need this...

```
Data_83: "He said, "Yes!" to the question"
```

to become this...

```
Data_83: "He said, Yes! to the question"
```

I am familiar with PHP and would like to use this. I know how to do something like...

```
<?php
$filename = 'path/to/file';
$content = file_get_contents($filename);
$new_content = str_replace('"', '', $content);
file_put_contents($filename, $new_content);
```

And I'm pretty sure a regular expression will be what I'm wanting to use to find the strings and remove the extra double quotation marks. But I'm very new to regular expressions and need some help here.

EDIT:

I should have mentioned, the file is a PHP file containing an object. It looks a bit like this:

```
<?php
$thing = {
    Data_83: "He said, "Yes!" to the question",
    Data_84: "Another string with "unwanted" quotes"
}
```

Comment: what is the format of your file? json?

Comment: sorry, I should have mentioned that, it's a PHP file containing an associative array

Comment: But the quotation marks within the quotation marks will throw a parse error

Comment: its not an associative array

Comment: Apply `str_replace` with foreach on this associative array.Also the array you shown is neither associative not an array ({} is not representation of array)

Comment: sorry, my bad, it's an object

Comment: make a live demo and clearly mention that what you are getting and what you want.

Comment: Struggling with regular expressions made tools like this quite useful: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as elegant but you could create a UDF:

```
function RemoveNestedQuotes($string)
{
    $firstPart = explode(":", $string)[0];
    preg_match('/"(.*)"/', $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    $tmpString = $matches[1][0];
    return $firstPart . ': "' . preg_replace('/"/', '', $tmpString) . '"';
}
```

example:

```
$string = 'Data_83: "He said, "Yes!" to the question"';

echo RemoveNestedQuotes($string);

// Data_83: "He said, Yes! to the question"
```

Comment: This has been fruitful. Thanks! I decided to use this by exploding the file contents at every PHP_EOL to get an array of lines, and then applying the above answer to each line and adding them to a result string to be written to the file. I had to check if $matches[1][0] was returning with each line and only appy the preg_replace to the line if it was set (isset) otherwise just add the line to the result. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `preg_replace_callback` with a regex like

```
'~^(\h*Data_\d{2,}:\h*")(.*)"~m'
```

Note that you may make it safer if you specify an optional `,` at the end of the line: `'~^(\h*Data_\d{2,}:\h*")(.*)",?\h*$~m'` but you might need to introduce another capturing group then (around `,?\h*`, and then append `$m[3]` in the `preg_replace_callback` callback function).

**Details**

- `^` - start of the line (`m` is a multiline modifier)
- `(\h*Data_\d{2,}:\h*")` - Group 1  (`$m[1]`):

  - `\h*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces
  - `Data_` - `Data_` substring
  - `\d{2,}` - 2 or more digits
  - `:` - a colon
  - `\h*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces
  - `"` - double quote
- `(.*)` - Group 2 (`$m[2]`): any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, up to the last...
- `"` - double quote (on a line).

The `$m` represents the whole match object, and you only need to remove the `"` inside `$m[2]`, the second capture.

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/OIXNWe):

```
preg_replace_callback('~^(\h*Data_\d{2,}:\h*")(.*)"~m', function($m) {
    return $m[1] . str_replace('"', '', $m[2]) . '"';
}, $content);
```

Comment: Sir your answer is very clear and exactly but, OP has changed their requirement and given condition is also different.

Comment: @RishiRaut This solution must work well for the scenario mentioned after the word `EDIT` in the question. It can be easily adjusted in case there are other conditions.

Comment: Extending this answer, if you want to just escape the double quotes to have them as actual content instead of replacing them, edit the str_replace like this:

`return $m[1] . str_replace('"', '\\"', $m[2]) . '"';`

Comment: I think Stribizew is right, the above answer doesn't work in my case, but it still gets an up-vote from me for being so thorough and explanatory

Answer (score 0):

One more step after `str_replace` with `implode` and `explode`. You can just do it like this.

```
<?php
$string = 'Data_83: "He said, "Yes!" to the question"';
$string = str_replace('"', '', $string);
echo $string =implode(': "',explode(': ',$string)).'"';
?>
```

Demo : https://eval.in/912466

**Program Output**

```
Data_83: "He said, Yes! to the question"
```

Just to replace `"` quotes

```
<?php
$string = 'Data_83: "He said, "Yes!" to the question"';
echo preg_replace('/"/', '', $string);
?>
```

Demo : https://eval.in/912457

Comment: the '83' and contents between the quotes is different for every string, and I have thousands of them

Comment: @PeterCullen : so just use `preg_replace` as in second example

Comment: but that will also replace the quotation marks the should be there

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, you don't need to make any `preg_replace_callback()` calls or a convoluted run of explosions and replacements.  You merely need to disqualify the 2 double quotes that you wish to retain and match the rest for removal.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2c730984b5b6eb26e2052eb4db185c80e7f33cc3))

```
$string = 'Data_83: "He said, "Yes!" to the question",
Data_184: "He said, "WTF!" to the question"';

echo preg_replace('/^[^"]+"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|"(?!,\R|$)/m','',$string);
```

Output:

```
Data_83: "He said, Yes! to the question",
Data_184: "He said, WTF! to the question"
```

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/b89juj/2)

```
/^[^"]+"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|"(?!,?$)/m
```

This pattern says:

- match from the start of each line until you reach the first double quote, then DISQUALIFY it.
- then after the `|`, match all double quotes that are not optionally followed by a comma then the end of line.

While this pattern worked on regex101 with my sample input, when I transferred it to the php sandbox to whack together a demo, I needed to add `\R` to maintain accuracy.  You can test to see which is appropriate for your server/environment.

Comment: @PeterCullen this is a clean/direct, single call replacement method.  If this doesn't work for your project, please clarify what the issue is so that I can update my answer.